# Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am in the process of trying to convert an Objective-C example to Swift 2, but I am running into a small issue. The original Objective-C snippet:

```
NSMutableArray *inputsOutputs = [NSMutableArray array];
...
[inputsOutputs addObject:@{@"input" : input, @"output" : trackOutput}];
```

and what I thought the Swift code should be:

```
var inputsOutputs = [Any?]()
...
inputsOutputs.append([ "input": input, "output": trackOutput ])
```

The resultant error is:

```
Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal?
```

How would I convert the Objective-C in this case to Swift?

Original Objective-C: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/avsubtitleswriterOSX/Listings/avsubtitleswriter_main_m.html

Comment: In my case, the answer was to add a cast to the Dictionary literal being assigned to `Any`... Unfortunately, I cannot come up with a simple example where this is necessary :(

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can see that the contents of the array are dictionaries with `String` keys and unknown values.

Therefore declare the array more specific

```
var inputsOutputs = [[String:AnyObject]]()
```

In Swift 3 for JSON collection types or if the dictionary / array contains only value types use

```
var inputsOutputs = [[String:Any]]()
```

Comment: Thanks, I had thought it was an array of JSON type objects. Not knowing ObjC, it not helping.

Answer (score 4):

It should be just fine, at least in Swift 2+. I just tried the following in a playground:

```
var objects = [Any?]()
let dict = [ "one" : 1, "two" : 2 ]
objects.append(dict)  // prints [{["one": 1, "two": 2]}]
objects.append([ "one" : 1, "two" : 2 ]) // prints [{["one": 1, "two": 2]}, {["one": 1, "two": 2]}]
```

Comment: I thought I was using Swift 2+, with XCode 7.2.1. Not sure where I would check for the Swift version conformance settings?

Comment: Xcode 7 uses Swift 2, so you've answered that question. Is it possible that the error you saw was on some *different* line? That's the kind of error that you'd see if you tried to use a subscript on an `AnyObject`.